# Reference another class in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Im learning flutter\dart and in my course the instructor has created the model and data as below. I noticed the List expenses in the Category class. Is it referencing the expense class? When do we reference external class? Is this similar to a join in SQL?

**Expense Model**

```
class Expense {
  final String name;
  final double cost;

  Expense({this.name, this.cost});
}
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category {
  final String name;
  final double maxAmount;
  final List<Expense> expenses;

  Category({this.name, this.maxAmount, this.expenses});
}
```

**Data**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter_budget_ui/models/category_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_budget_ui/models/expense_model.dart';

final rand = Random();

final List<double> weeklySpending = [
  rand.nextDouble() * 100,
  rand.nextDouble() * 100,
  rand.nextDouble() * 100,
  rand.nextDouble() * 100,
  rand.nextDouble() * 100,
  rand.nextDouble() * 100,
  rand.nextDouble() * 100,
];

_generateExpenses() {
  List<Expense> expenses = [
    Expense(name: 'Item 0', cost: rand.nextDouble() * 90),
    Expense(name: 'Item 1', cost: rand.nextDouble() * 90),
    Expense(name: 'Item 2', cost: rand.nextDouble() * 90),
    Expense(name: 'Item 3', cost: rand.nextDouble() * 90),
    Expense(name: 'Item 4', cost: rand.nextDouble() * 90),
    Expense(name: 'Item 5', cost: rand.nextDouble() * 90),
  ];
  return expenses;
}

List<Category> categories = [
  Category(name: 'Food', maxAmount: 450, expenses: _generateExpenses()),
  Category(name: 'Clothing', maxAmount: 500, expenses: _generateExpenses()),
  Category(name: 'Utilities', maxAmount: 600, expenses: _generateExpenses()),
  Category(
      name: 'Entertainment', maxAmount: 330, expenses: _generateExpenses()),
  Category(
      name: 'Transportation', maxAmount: 500, expenses: _generateExpenses()),
  Category(name: 'Housing', maxAmount: 1000, expenses: _generateExpenses()),
];
```

Comment: You could think of it as modelling a has-many relationship. A `Category` has many `Expense`s. In fact, in Dart, it has a `List` of them.

Comment: You can create a model that contains another model in dart.

Comment: Thanks. How do i mark this question as Answered as the both replies are in the comments section?